# Java regex pattern group capture

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split the string below into 3 groups, but with it doesn't seem to be working as expected with the pattern that I'm using. Namely, when I invoke `matcher.group(3)`, I'm getting a null value instead of `*;+g.3gpp.cs-voice;require`. What's wrong with the pattern?

String: `"*;+g.oma.sip-im;explicit,*;+g.3gpp.cs-voice;require"`

Pattern: `(\\*;.*)?(\\*;.*?\\+g.oma.sip-im.*?)(,\\*;.*)?`

Expected:

Group 1: `null`,
Group 2: `*;+g.oma.sip-im;explicit`,
Group 3: `,*;+g.3gpp.cs-voice;require`

Actual:

Group 1: `null`,
Group 2: `*;+g.oma.sip-im`,
Group 3: `null`

Comment: Why aren't you just splitting on `,`?

Comment: @TheLostMind: Because it would yield incorrect/unexpected results.

Comment: Could just use `[*][^,*]+` and get the matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Well, he has just 1 comma there.It would give incorrect results if he had multiple commas

Answer (score 0):

The result you get does actually match your pattern in a non-greedy way. Group2 is expanded to the shortest possible result

```
*;+g.oma.sip-im
```

and then the last group is left out because of the question mark at the very end. It appears to me that you are building a far too complicated regex for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the `(,\*;.*)?` does not match as the text you expect is located further in the string. You need to make the third group *obligatory* by removing the `?` at the end, but wrap the whole `.*?` + Group 3 within an optional non-capturing group:

```
String pat = "(\\*;.*)?(\\*;.*?\\+g\\.oma\\.sip-im)(?:.*?(,\\*;.*))?";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/95TOKh/2).

Note that literal dots should be escaped in the regex pattern.

**Details**:

- `(\\*;.*)?` - Group 1 (optional) capturing

  - `\\*;` - a `*;` string
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than linebreak symbols, as many as possible
- `(\\*;.*?\\+g\\.oma\\.sip-im)` - Group 2 (obligatory) capturing

  - `\\*;` - a `*;` string
  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than linebreak symbols, as few as possible
  - `\\+g\\.oma\\.sip-im`  - a literal string `+g.oma.sip-im`
- `(?:.*?(,\\*;.*))?` - non-capturing group (optional) matching

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than linebreak symbols, as few as possible
  - `(,\\*;.*)` - Group 3 (obligatory) capturing the same pattern as in Group 1.